# Visualization of a slit annulus?

Tags: complex-analysis

I have come across the following description of a slit annulus:

$$ \sqrt{e} < |z| < e^2, z \notin(-e^2, -\sqrt{e})$$

I am confused what this means. The first part makes good enough sense. It is an annulus and the outer radius is $e$ and the inner radius is $\sqrt{e}$. Does the second part mean that it is only the positive real axis? Or does it mean that its the annulus but not the part that is on the negative real axis?

Comment: Yes,  it is the annulus without the part on the negative real axis. The removed part is the slit.

Answer (score 2):

Nevermind. Thought about it for a second and it just means without the negative real axis. It's just saying that $x + iy \notin (-e^2 + 0i, -\sqrt{e} + 0i)$.